# PHP - reliable deliver of documents inline to the browser

Tags: php

Is there a library or good documentation somewhere on the best way to reliably deliver documents in a users browser regardless of OS and browser.  I'm mainly looking at PDF, office (2003 & 2007) and scanned images (.tiff)  It seems that you always have to set different headers depending on the browser and the type of document being delivered.  Right now:

```
header("Content-Type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$name");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: private");
```

Seems to work most often for IE but not always for FF.

Comment: You want a way to force the browser to display these files?  I'm sorry to say that this may not be possible they way you want.  The browser decides what to do with certain filetypes, and many times, the user can tell the browser what to do (like in FF).  For example, I have mine set to always open .pdf files with my favorite PDF viewer, rather than display them in the browser.

Comment: My issue is I'm not 100% sure what needs to go into the header to get the document to appear inline if at all possible.  It seems to me that there is some sort of magic combination that is required based on file type to display inline.  If the user has their system set to open a PDF in Acrobat or Preview I'm fine with that...I'd just like them to not have to download...search for the file...then open it if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code you have is probably about what it's gonna take. The problem is that for every browser you're going to need a variant on that code, so you're going to end up with a fairly complicated browser detection library with a bunch of special cases in it.

If inlining is really important to you I'd consider ripping them to a more web friendly format on the server and just serving that. You can always leave a "download" link at the bottom for the source file. [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) can convert most formats to .png/.gifs, and you could use something like [pdftohtml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/) to rip the PDF's. There are some libraries that will do this for word documents, too, although the ones google spit out at me immediately were non-free.